# Swift filter function

Tags: swift

I am trying to remove null value for key in dictionary
so I have this kind of data:

```
let dic = ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov", "Website": NSNull(),"About": NSNull()]
        let array = [dic,2,3,4]
        let jsonResult:[String: AnyObject] = ["FirstName": "Anvar", "LastName": "Azizov", "Website": array,"About": NSNull()]
        let jsonCleanDictionary = filter(jsonResult, {!($0.1 is NSNull)})
```

can not understand syntax of above filter function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use NSNull() in swift instead prefer using `nil`. Further, since its a dictionary adding keys with a null value is pretty useless since dictionaries will return nil if the key doesn't exist. So when checking for null all you have to do is

```
if let some = dic["key"] as? Value {
    // some now contains the value inside dic's key as a value type of Value. 
}
```

Also the filter function works by taking a block which returns a bool so:

```
dict.filter { (key, value) -> Bool in 
    // Do stuff to check key and value and return a 
    // bool which is true if you want that key, value pair to 
    // appear in the filtered result. 
}
```

In swift closure arguments can get anonymous names if not explicitly return. These names are of the format `$0`, `$1`, etc. Now, the filter function takes only parameter specifically the `Self.Generator.Element` from the `CollectionType` protocol. For dictionaries this is a tuple containing the key and the value. To access members of unnamed tuples you use `.0`, `.1`, `.2`, etc. depending on the index of the tuple member. So for dictionaries `Self.Generator.Element` is a tuple containing the key and the value. So $0.1 refers to the value of the key,value pair. Hope this clears this weird syntax up a little bit.

Comment: ok thnx...but in filter func above $0 is closure argument but what meaning of $0.1?